# SQL select different things to the same column based on result count from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have 3 tables

```
Employees        EmployeePossitionsOverYears      Position
- Id             - EmployeeId                     - Id
- Firstname      - Year                           - Name
- LastName       - PositionId
```

I need to select the list of Employees with their positions.

If employee position doesn't change over the years (every row of EmployeePossitionsOverYears table where EmployeeId = 1 PossitionId = 6) I need to select only the position name.

But if employee position changes (at least one of PositionId is not like the others where EmployeeId = 3) I need to select all position names with their respective years for that employee to a single `nvarchar` column.

I can't really join EmployeePossitionsOverYears table to Employees table because that causes the same employees to be selected multiple times.

I've tried using CASE in something like

```
select
PositionText = 
CASE 
(select count(*) from 
(select Distinct EmployeeId, PositionId from EmployeePossitionsOverYears where EmployeeId = Employees.Id))
```

But that doesn't work because I still can't select without joining EmployeePossitionsOverYears table.

How would I select only 1 Position name if all of the PositionIds are the same for a given employee but select all of position names + their years if there are at least 2 different PositionIds into a single column without having more rows then there are employees?

Example:

Employees

```
Id  FirstName  LastName
1   First      Emp
2   Second     Worker
3   Third      Person
```

EmployeePossitionsOverYears

```
EmployeeId  Year    PositionId
1           2010    1
1           2011    1
1           2012    1
2           2010    1
2           2011    2
2           2012    3
3           2010    1
3           2011    2
3           2012    1
```

Position

```
Id  Name
1   Junior
2   Middle
3   Senior
```

Expected result:

```
FirstName  LastName   position
- First     - Emp       - Junior
- Second    - Worker    - 2010_Junior, 2011_Middle, 2012_Senior 
- Third     - Person    - 2010_Junior, 2011_Middle, 2012_Junior
```

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: provide some sample data and your expected output in table format

Comment: @Fahmi provided some example data and my expected result

Comment: What if someone was had position 1 in 2010 and 2011 and then position 2 in 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make it like this.

```
with cte as(
    select
        EmployeePossitionsOverYears.*,
        Position.Name
    from EmployeePossitionsOverYears
    inner join Position on Position.Id = EmployeePossitionsOverYears.PositionId)

select
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    -- count the number of unique PositionId
    case when count(distinct PositionId) = 1
        -- There is no change in position.
        then max(Position.name)
        -- If there is a change in position, edit with the year.
        else replace((select concat([year] , '_' , Name) as [data()]
                   from cte
                   where EmployeeId = EmployeePossitionsOverYears.EmployeeId
                   order by [year]
                   for xml path ('')), ' ', ',') 
    end AS MemberNames
from EmployeePossitionsOverYears
inner join Employees on Employees.id = EmployeePossitionsOverYears.EmployeeId
inner join Position on Position.Id = EmployeePossitionsOverYears.PositionId
group by EmployeeId, FirstName, LastName
```

If you are using SQLServer 2017 or later, you can write smarter using the string_agg function.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to express this is:

```
select e.FirstName, e.LastName,
       (case when count(distinct p.name) = 1
             then max(p.name)
             else string_agg(concat(epy.year, '_', p.name), ', ' order by epy.year)
        end) as positions
from employees e join
     EmployeePossitionsOverYears epy
     on e.id = epy.EmployeeId join
     Position p
     on p.Id = epy.PositionId
group by e.id, e.FirstName, e.LastName;
```

However, I would expect that you would want to combine adjacent years with the same position.  For that, window functions can determine when positions change:

```
select e.FirstName, e.LastName,
       (case when count(distinct p.name) = 1
             then max(p.name)
             else string_agg(case when prev_position is null or prev_position <> position then concat(epy.year, '_', p.name) end, ', ')
        end) as positions
from (select ep.*,
             lag(position) over (partition by id order by year) as prev_position_year
      from (select e.id, e.firstname, e.lastname, epy.name, p.name as position
            from employees e join
                 EmployeePossitionsOverYears epy
                 on e.id = epy.EmployeeId join
                 Position p
                 on p.Id = epy.PositionId
           ) ep
     ) ep
group by e.id, e.FirstName, e.LastName;
```